# Could the projects name contain a dot?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm runing MVC 2RC project on IIS 5.1.

When default created project is named "MvcApplication1" than everythig is ok. But when projects name is "MvcApplication1.Web" (contain ".") than I get an error during the debug: ***"unable to start debugging on the web server. the web server could not find the requested resource"***

Do someone know how to resolve this problem?

Thanks a lot, Igor

Comment: Works on my machine.™ I think you need to give more information. The dot in the project name alone is not the whole issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a problem with namespaces and classes. This is like trying to name a class in php My$Class or in C My->Class...it's just not possible.

Comment: a restriction, rather than a problem, i'd say. the limit seems perfectly reasonable to me. +1, tho

Comment: Strange. I have periods in my project names and they're absolutely fine.

Comment: Why it's impossible? In asp.net Web Forms it's just ok, for example http://www.tiptopdevelopment.com/GoodsFinder.Portal/

Comment: @Dan - Is it because OP is using IIS 5.1? I too have dots in my project names

Comment: I don't know why. I have not problem with iis 5 for asp.net web forms, where "." was in url like in previous comment